# Probability no two pairs are grouped together twice in a row?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is a room with 48 people divided into 16 groups of 3 in round 1. In round 2, the group is again randomly divided into 16 groups. What is the probability that no two groupmates in round one are in the same group again in round two?

#### Progress

I thought at first that if you label two arbitrary people A and B then the probability that they will not be in the same group in round two if they were in round one is $1/21$ (from $3/63$). From there I thought maybe do $1 - (1/21)*$the number of possible pairs, but that will yield a negative answer.

Comment: Excellent question, but as nobody wants to reinvent the wheel, please tell us your thoughts so far so people can help point this in the right direction.

Comment: Are the groups labeled?

Comment: Hi guys,well I thought at first that if you label two arbitrary people A and B then the prob that they will not be in the same group in round two if they were in round one is 1/21 (3/63). From there I thought maybe do 1 - 1/21 * the number of possible pairs, but that will yield a negative answer

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the goal in round 2 is that each person is grouped with two new people, as opposed to "I was in group 7 in round 1 and I'm in group 7 again in round 2." I am proceeding according to this assumption. Also, I am not new to Mathematics or Probability, but I am new to entering formulas on this website. Please pardon my lack of LaTeX skills, and feel free to edit this or re-post with the fractions properly presented. Thank you.

Round 1 can be represented by a regular 48-gon. Suppose P1 is one vertex of the polygon, and P2 and P3 are its neighbors (that is, an edge of the polygon connects P1 to P2, and another edge connects P1 to P3.) Then, these two edges, plus the diagonal between P2 and P3, forms a triangle. P1, P2, and P3 represent the members of one of the 16 groups. Continue this pattern for the rest of the vertices of the polygon, and you will have 16 triangles, representing the 16 groups of three people.

In round 2, then, brand new triangles will be formed, apparently at random, using any of the edges and diagonals of the polygon. There are 48*47/2 = 1128 total edges and diagonals in the polygon. 48 of them will be chosen to use in the triangles. So there are 1128 C 48 different possibilities of grouping the people. However, there are 48 lines that we do not want to draw in round 2: those that were used in round 1. We can draw any of the other lines in round 2, so there are (1128 - 48) C 48 possibilities for groups in round 2, without using any of the pairings from round 1.

Thus, the probability that each person will be grouped with two new people in round 2 is 1080 C 48 divided by 1128 C 48 = 0.11848.

Comment: You can't choose the edges at random in round 2, as that does not guarantee that the 48 edges form 16 triangles.

Comment: Oops! That was a silly mistake on my part... Back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a summary of [vixra:2306.0157](https://vixra.org/abs/2306.0157) : There are $b=3$ members per group and $u=16$ groups and also $u$ tables in the room.

The question is, if we have $ub$ people and consider all $(ub)!$ permutations, distribute the first $b$ people in the permutation at the first table, the second $b$ people at the second table and so on, what is the probability that there is at least one table with at least two people of the same group?

The complementary problem (with the probability equal one minus that probability): What is the probability that at all tables all people are from distinct groups, i.e., what is the probability that at all tables the people are from b distinct groups?

It is more efficient to assume that the groups are distinguished by $u$ colors and that problem is to distribute a multiset of balls of $u$ colors, each color occuring $b$ times, across $u$ urns, $b$ balls per urn, and to ask for the probability that in each urn all colors are distinct.  This means that we consider only $(ub)!/(b!)^u$ permutations of the multiset of balls, see https://oeis.org/A060538 or for $b=3$ in particular https://oeis.org/A014606 . The probability does not change with that type or reduction (or making people anonymous by recognizing only their color) because the recontres (balls of the same color in the same urn) remain the same for each of the $b!$ permutations in each of the $u$ groups.

There is a matrix representation of these multiset permutations by nonnegative $u\times u$ integer matrices. It contains in rows enumerated by colors (say 0-based colors are from 0 to u-1) and in columns enumerated by urns (urns also from 0 to u-1) how many balls of that color are assigned to that urn.

For example with $b=2$ and $u=4$ the permutation of the 8 balls may be 23302011 . To illustrate the assignment to urns put bars in that permutation: 23|30|20|11 . The associated matrix indicates that the two 0's end up at table 1 and 2, the two 1's at table 3, etc:

0110

0002

1010

1100

This type of matrices is counted in [A257493](https://oeis.org/A257493) . We are interested to count the subset of matrices without rencontres,
i.e. the subset of matrices where all entries in these matrices are at most 1, see [A008300](https://oeis.org/A008300) and in particular for $b=3$ [A001501](https://oeis.org/A001501) . By dividing the associated numbers of these OEIS sequences we obtain the following probabilities of non-rencontres for $b=3$:

u=3: 1*(3!)^3 /1680 = 216/1680 = 0.12857

u=4: 24*(3!)^4 /369600 = 0.08415584

u=5: 2040*(3!)^5 /168168000 = 0.0943285

u=6: 297200*(3!)^6 /137225088000 = 0.10104685

u=7: 68938800*(3!)^7 /182509367040000 = 0.10573951

...

u=16: 190637228506535883540302038364160000 *(3!)^16 / 4400365813372582601747033381701114920960000000000
= 22412492056099268610796280934 /  183379679297107265230867984375
= 0.12221906.

So the probability is roughly 12.221 percent.